# How do we integrate the test evidences with X-Ray Jira via API's?

Tags: selenium, rest, cucumber, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I want to upload the test evidences of an automation tests to the X-Ray Jira through API.
I need what API and Endpoint is being consumed to upload the test execution evidences to X-Ray Jira.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on the documentation regarding the API of Xray here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Version+2

You also have multiple tutorials showcasing importing results from different tools and frameworks here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/TTT%3A+Automation

Make sure you use the right documentation version depending on your Jira installation: Cloud or Server/DC. The above documentation is for Cloud (you can find the same one for Server).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resources. I would like to get a step by step process of integrating, If possible any video walkthroughs of the complete process.

Comment: You can look at examples for importing test results using Cucumber in Java here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+Cucumber+in+Java

Comment: We also have an academy with videos showcasing integration with test automation: https://academy.getxray.app/catalog/info/id:129

Comment: evidence (e.g., screenshot) support depends on the report format you'll use